# Channels or categories?

Tags: expressionengine

I've exported about 2000 forum posts (split between 9 forum categories), each with up to 10 replies.

I'm importing them as channel entries and comments. Would it be best to use a single channel and assign a category to each entry, or have a channel for each old forum category?

Thanks for any opinions.

Best wishes
Lee

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting them up as a single Channel would probably give you a little more flexibility moving forward with Categories. If you break them down into their own separate Channels moving Entries around will be tougher. Plus it's easier to setup Categories (and you can setup member groups that you can give access to if you had others helping you manage these) and WAY easier to move entries around. I know that forums see visitors posting in wrong sections all the time. With the Category system you could move them around as needed. Gives you a LOT more flexibility in my mind.

I hope that helps!

Comment: I also think this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go with a single channel, since moving an entry to another category (and therefor another forum ) only takes one click, while having to move it to another channel is a lot more difficult.